# URL to fill input fields

Tags: html, http

There is a website that I use regularly that has quite a few log in fields. I'm trying to formulate a link to pre-populate most of them.
The fields in question are formatted like this:

```
<input id="frm:User" type="text" name="frm:User" autocomplete="off" style="width:80%" />
```

I've tried using "http://website?frm:User=User&frmGroup=Group" to no avail. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There exists no standard way to fill in HTML inputs by passing values into the URL's query string. The URL including the query string parameters is sent to the server as a request, and the server generates the HTML as a response. It's completely up to the remote server how to interpret the incoming query parameters and how to generate the HTML.

What is the reason exactly you want the fields for this particular site to be auto filled? Maybe a password manager like lastpass could do the trick for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome, this can be done pretty easily with [Autofill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk) extension. All you need to do is:

1. Install Autofill extension.
2. Open the website page that you want to auto fill input fields. Activate the Autofill extension.
3. Fill the input fields manually and then save it to a profile.
4. Click "Generate Autofill Rules". Next time, when you visit this page, the input fields will be filled automatically.